# How does one login with a url command(Test Handle), rather than entering in each step?

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

So, the scenario is to login to said website using a formatted url, rather than doing something like what is below. Upon reading documentation regarding Selenium etc i read that this is bad practice (Excluding a login test case).  I understand that the method i am inquiring about is not to be used on production level.
 Does the url method pull the login information from a database?

```
//ENTER AGENT LOGIN ID
                IWebElement LoadAgentLoginID2 = selenium.FindElement(By.Id("MainContent_txtAgentID"));
                LoadAgentLoginID2.Click();
                LoadAgentLoginID2.SendKeys(AgentLoginIDs[0]);

                //ENTER ARC NUMBER
                IWebElement LoadARCnumber2 = selenium.FindElement(By.Id("MainContent_txtArcNbr"));
                LoadARCnumber2.Click();
                LoadARCnumber2.SendKeys(System.String.Format("{0}", ARCnumbers[1]));

                //ENTER PASSWORD
                IWebElement LoadPassword2 = selenium.FindElement(By.Id("MainContent_txtPassword"));
                LoadPassword2.Click();
                LoadPassword2.SendKeys(AgentPasswords[0]);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Might not be the best question to ask a selenium crowd. Selenium interacts with the browser similarly to the way a user would. Furthermore If a regular user can get around a sign up by entering a test handle, why do you need selenium to automate that process? Why not just use a javascript command?

Comment: Websites do that with the help of GET or POST methods. If it's GET then there is the URL that you can construct (something along the lines of @RogerCampbell answer), if it's POST then you can execute javascript code for that post. There is no "general" answer for your question.

Comment: In response to Greg Rehm.  The user would not be able to do so(which is why i made the comment regarding production level :) ).  I ask because the idea was to skip the login process( to execute another test, such as putting something in the shopping cart).  The login process would have already been tested with the selenium above.  You would not want tests to rely on each other where it can be avoided, as it contributes to flakiness (correct me if i'm wrong :)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url method needs to be supported by the web application.  If this is supported, then it would simply be something like this:

driver.get("http://www.mywebapp.com?username=JohnP&password=ABCD");

If the web app does not support this, then you should just try to encapsulate your login logic above into a separate and reusable method.